# Get camera ISO / shutter speed using CameraX or Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm trying to get the current preview's shutter speed and ISO settings.

I cannot find a way to do this using CameraX or Camera2. Is this not something that is available?

Failing that, is there a way to get the settings that were used to take a photo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Camera2, this information is available in the [CaptureResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult) objects you get for every captured image, via [onCaptureCompleted](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback#onCaptureCompleted(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult)). However, not all devices support listing this information; only devices that list the [READ_SENSOR_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_READ_SENSOR_SETTINGS:kotlin.Int) capability will do this.  That includes all devices that list hardware level [FULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#info_supported_hardware_level_full) or better, and may include some devices at the LIMITED level.

Specifically, you want to look at [SENSOR_SENSITIVITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#sensor_sensitivity) for ISO and [SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#sensor_exposure_time) for shutter speed.

If you want the values used for a JPEG capture, look at the CaptureResult that comes from the CaptureRequest you used to request the JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

I also was able to **GET only** the ISO settings using Jetpack/CameraX API through the [Camera2CameraInfo.from](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/camera2/interop/Camera2CameraInfo#from(androidx.camera.core.CameraInfo)) and then [getCameraCharacteristic](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/camera2/interop/Camera2CameraInfo#getCameraCharacteristic(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics.Key%3CT%3E)). But it seems there is no way to **set** them (using CameraX).

Comment: Ladisl do you have any example how to use Camera2CameraInfo ? at least get the instance, thank you

Comment: @PontiacGTX
 use the Camera2CameraInfo.from( ) method to get the instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest releases of Jetpack/CameraX it is also possible to **set** the ISO/ShutterSpeed.
The below example sets the ISO for preview (written in C# language, but it is similar to Java):

```
var builder = new Preview.Builder();
var ext1 = new Camera2Interop.Extender(builder)
    .SetCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.ControlAeMode, (int)ControlAEMode.Off)
    .SetCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.SensorSensitivity, 3200);
            
var preview = builder.SetTargetName("PREVIEW").Build();
preview.SetSurfaceProvider(sfcPreview.SurfaceProvider);
```